# CustomView in android throws inflate exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, inflate-exception

I have to create a custom view in my android application, for that I have wrote code as follows

**xml**

```
<com.package.custom.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**CustomView.java**

```
package com.package.custom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {

    Paint customPaint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        customPaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();
        customPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        customPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        customPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark));
        canvas.drawPaint(customPaint);
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class CustomViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_button);
        CustomView customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.my_view);

    }   
}
```

but while I am running the application I am getting error ::

```
3178-3178/com.package.custom E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.custom/com.package.custom.CustomViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.package.custom.CustomView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
```

What is the reason ? is there any problem in my code ? how do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change:

```
public class CustomView extends TextView {

    Paint customPaint;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    customPaint = new Paint();
}
```

Name of the class constructor are not the same.

`View` class does not have method `android:text=""` change base class to `TextView`

Comment: what is the difference between extending View and TextView ? if it works with TextView it should work with View also. so logically this is incorrect

Comment: `View` class does not have method `android:text=""` change base class to `TextView`

Comment: deleted that, but same

Comment: `CustomView` is not using the `2` or `3-arguments` `View` constructors... See my edit..

Comment: after passing attribute set object it works. how do I set background color taking from the xml attribute defined for the view ?